# How to generate all possible sequences for 8 possible parameters

Tags: matlab, sequence

I'm trying to come up with a way to auto generate all possible sequences for 8 total parameters.

When I say sequences here is what I mean:

8 total parameters available (A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H).
I need to generate a list of all the possible sequences starting with only selecting one parameter by itself. So the numbers in the example below show the order in which the parameters will be selected. So no number can be repeated in the same row.

Example of the start of the sequences:

[image]

Can this be done somehow in Matlab or even VBA?

Comment: What do the numbers mean?

Comment: The numbers are just the order in which the parameters are selected. So, no numbers can be repeated in the same row.

Comment: Before you try to do it, compute how many of them you will have. This looks like you will need more RAM than what you have, but I am bad a combinatorics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start with ndgrid.  You can adapt what's below:

```
[X,Y] = ndgrid(1:2:19,2:2:12);

ctr = 1;
for i = 1:size(X,1)
  for j = 1:size(Y,2)
    params(ctr,:) = [X(i,1), Y(1,j)];
    ctr = ctr+1;
  end
end
```

Comment: Isn't that double loop the same as `params = [X(:), Y(:)]`?